# Конфликт интересов при выборе направления программирования

Tags: python, c++, swift, машинное-обучение

Возможно, вопрос не по теме, но я пока не нашел форума (кроме SO), где достаточно много программистов, которые смогут чем-либо мне помочь.

Проблема такая. Я изучал swift и немного obj-c разработку, мне очень понравились эти инструменты, они лаконичные, очень мощные и красивые, хотя сфера программирования, вроде создания desktop-приложения под Mac и IOS меня не привлекает. То есть, кратко, мне нравится инструмент, но не нравится сфера применения. Сфера, которая меня привлекает - машинное обучение, я люблю математику и ML и считаю, что для меня это будет просто шикарной работой, но в ML используется в основном python, намного реже - С++ (который тоже нравится, как инструмент). Иронично, но в таком случае мне нравится сфера, но не нравится основной инструмент - язык python, который просто отталкивает меня. Что вы, дорогие стекопереполненовцы, можете предложить в качестве решения проблемы?

Comment: *"obj-c разработку, мне очень понравились эти инструменты, они лаконичные, очень мощные и красивые"*, *"С++ (который тоже нравится"* - закусывать надо

Comment: Ну может действительно человек что то нашел красивое. Но может посмотреть на другие языки. Может мнение ещё поменяется

Comment: Как насчёт `C#`? Для него тоже есть довольно неплохие библиотеки `ML`. Хотя, конечно, на питоне всё как-то проще было бы.

Comment: @KoVadim, согласен. Постарался описать в ответе, как поменять мнение:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Амур, если коротко, то ориентироваться всё же логичнее на то, что делать ("сфера применения"), чем на то, чем делать ("стек технологий"). Первое: a)  шире и б) ближе к тому, что можно назвать "что я делаю в жизни".

Если чуть детальнее, то в целом, программист, не способный или не желающий при необходимости сменить стек технологий, ограничивает своё профессиональное развитие, а также снижает свою конкурентоспособность на рынке труда. Если программирование является лишь хобби, то можно себе позволить работать с языком в терминах "люблю-не люблю" ("отталкивает-притягивает"). Если же это ещё и способ обеспечения себя и семьи (имеющейся или будущей), то необходимо, как минимум, разобраться, в чём именно проблема.

В вашем вопросе отстутствует ясное объяснение, почему язык отталкивает, а надо начать с этого. Так как язык - всего лишь инструмент. При этом с массой возможностей (в случае Python). С определённой степенью в результате анализа выяснится, что просто  нет глубокого понимания, зачем язык такой, и какие возможности он даёт, а также, что время, потраченное на его изучение слишком мало, чтобы овладеть его особенностями.
В этом случае, если есть достаточно воли, нужно: а) понять сильные стороны языка (включая зачем он такой, что у него "под капотом" и т.д.); б) потратить достаточно времени, чтобы достичь умения писать на нём (в соответствии с его стилем!) не хуже, чем на предпочитаемом языке.

Я сам ранее несколько лет хорошо, быстро и структурированно писал на С, а когда сейчас задумался, не вернуться ли к разработке ПО, то решил сфокусироваться на быстрорастущем ML. Python меня достаточно сильно удивил своей относительной противоположностью С, там мало того, что мне нравилось в С (одно запихивание всего в одну строку чего стоит, или динамическая типизация). Но эти же вещи и являются его сильной стороной и придают ему своё очарование. Надо просто их понять, им научиться и полюбить их:-)

Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне помогли!